# Nesting in Enum?

Tags: c#, enums, unity-game-engine

(I hope this is a right description for what I want to achieve - feel free to change the title)

I'm making a small game, that will have different *GameStates*. Normally I would place these in an `enum`. But this time I want to do the following:

```
enum GameState
{
    Menu
    Game.Playing
    Game.Paused
    ...
}
```

Which obviously doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: Solve what? Explain the _exact_ problem you are trying to solve here.

Comment: Is `Game.Playing` a member of another enum called `Game`, or do you just wish to prefix the word "Game" on some of the elements?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just using `Game_Playing`, `Game_Paused`, etc.?

Comment: `Game` would be an `enum` as well, but belongs in the `GameState enum`.

Comment: Well never mind, stupid question now that I think about it.

Comment: It's not stupid, it just sounds awfully contrived.  The answer is, you can't do that.  If it's not contrived, give us the exact scenario in full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it *really* necessary? Or can you just use

```
enum GameState
{
    Menu
    Game_Playing
    Game_Paused
    ...
}
```

If you really need some advanced behavior, you're going to need a more intelligent enum, made up of classes, and sub-classes. Something like:

```
abstract class GameState { }
class Menu : GameState { }
class Game : GameState
{
    private class _Playing : GameState { }
    private class _Paused : GameState { }

    static readonly GameState Playing = new _Playing();
    static readonly GameState Paused = new _Paused();
}
```

Is that really worth it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now that I think about it, it was a stupid question and I can indeed solve it this way.

Comment: I think this line didn't get edited completely after it was pasted: `static readonly GameState Paused = new _Playing();`

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to do this directly, but you can "simulate" nested enums with nested `static` classes.

Simple but not strongly typed approach:

```
static class GameState
{
    public const int Menu = 0;

    public static class Game
    {
        public const int Playing = 1;
        public const int Paused = 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't define nested Enum, but you can use multible enums inside a class but it will not be like tree structure.

```
public static class GameState
 {
    public enum Game {
        Playing,
        Paused,
        ,etc..
    }

    public enum Menu {
        Menu1,
        Menu2
    }
}
```